# How connect audio player's volume control with sound of local notification?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, uilocalnotification, uislider

I have an application in which i have set a notification for show at particular time and date. Now i want to control volume of sound of notification  by `UISlider` or audio player. How do I control the sound of the notification in my application by applying a `UISlider`?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider{

    player.volume=slider.value;

 [audioPlayer setVolume:setPlayerVolume];
}
```